Userelationship, datebetween, filter in a DAX
I have a table which has an active relationship with date table (i.e. Date completed). Yet I have another DAX would like to use another date field (i.e. Date commenced) and link with date table, in order to be able to use the date slicer for filter in the PowerBI dashboard. I am not sure if my expression particularly the RETURN part is wrong, as it still shows blank when I move the slicer....
Number of Assessments In Progress = 
VAR SelectedStakeholders = VALUES(Stakeholders[Company Name] )
VAR SelectedSites = 
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        CALCULATETABLE( 
            Sites, 
            FILTER( 
                Sites,
                Sites[Applicant.lookupValue] IN SelectedStakeholders 
                || Sites[Owner.lookupValue] IN SelectedStakeholders 
                || Sites[Manager.lookupValue] IN SelectedStakeholders
                ||Sites[Tenant(s).lookupValue] IN SelectedStakeholders ||Sites[Contractor.lookupValue] IN SelectedStakeholders 
            )
        ),
        "SiteID", Sites[ID]
    )
RETURN
CALCULATE( 
    DISTINCTCOUNT( Assessments[Assessment Title] ), 
    USERELATIONSHIP(Assessments[Date Commenced],'Date'[Date]),
    DATESBETWEEN(Assessments[Date Commenced],'Measure'[Start Date],'Measure'[EndDate])
)

blank in dashboard when changing the date slicer :


Does this answer your question? Power BI DAX Not getting correct results when counting rows with FILTER and USERELATIONSHIP

Additionally, where is [Start Date] and [EndDate] coming from? Do you need USERELATIONSHIP and DATESBETWEEN together?
